# Doing something whenever an object gets disposed

Tags: c#

Consider the following class :

```
public class SomeObject
{
        public string x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }

        private void Serialize(){}
        //When the object gets collected by the GC want to call the Serialize() function
}
```

What event should I use for that purpose?

I want to call the function when the GC collects the object or when the application closes, but I want to do it from inside the class

Comment: What do you mean by "disposed"? You are not talking about `IDisposable`, right? Will [Object.Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx) work?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight all i need is calling that method wether when the application closes or when that object gets collected by the GC

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do? While the Finalizer seems like the correct place, this seems like a really bad idea (given the various uncertanities associated with it, and the different ways you can seriously break your app when using a finalizer).

Comment: If you need to catch application exiting, there are Events for that (e.g., AppDomain.OnUnload). But keep in mind that I can kill an app at any time (e.g. through the task manager) and circumvent all of the graceful events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really, really, need to do something when the object is collected, then you would use the [`Finalize` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Normally the Finalizer method is only used as a backup for when objects are not disposed properly, to try to wipe up most of the mess.

There is no guarantee that the Finalizer method is actually executed for all objects, so it's not a reliable way to clean up objects. When the application ends, the garbage collector spends some time to collect objects and run Finalize methots for those that implement it, but if that process takes too long, it will just abandon the rest of the objects and let the application close.

An object that needs to do something when it's not used any more, should implement the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IDisposable.aspx). Note however that it doesn't mean that the object will do anything automatically, it's the responsibility of the programmer using the object to dispose of it correctly.

Comment: how long is too long?

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph, that's the only course of action that needs to be taken here.

Comment: @user1492051: That's an implementation detail in the garbage collector, and I can't recall seeing an exact number for that, but it would be something like a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not call the `Serialize()` method in the destructor:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    private void Serialize(){}

    ~SomeObject() {
      Serialize();
    }

}
```

Comment: Finalizers are not guaranteed to run.

Comment: so that gets called when the application closes and whenever the GC collects that object?

Comment: well most disposable objects use the GC.SuppressFinalizer method when the object got already disposed. As a result, the finalizer won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

Public override OnDispose. But Your class must implement IDisposable for this.